# VS2017 Nuget pthread LNK1120 unresolved

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, nuget, pthreads, lnk2019

I heard that Nuget builds project easier without any configuration.

So, I am trying to add pthreads in my project from Nuget

(Actually I am using windows 10 x64 Visual studio 2017, C language, and my friends use linux OS)

I just search pthreads in Nuget package, click "install" button

But, my project compiles well but `fatal error LNK1120` called.

## Is there any more configuration after install pthreads from nuget?

- The reason why I ask this simple question in stackoverflow is that, there is no more steps in [Microsoft official guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio).

Comment: Set Build log to detailed by Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Build and Run-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `detailed` and then share the detailed error log with us. Also, what is your project type, a console or a window project? Or provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example is better for us to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @hellogod I am not using English, so, there is error ```main.obj : error LNK2019: __imp__pthread_create``` ```main.obj : error LNK2019: __imp__pthread_join``` ```fatal error LNK1120:```

Comment: can you tell us what your project type is or is it created in VS2017?

Comment: VS2017, new project - ConsoleApplication. There is no other things that I manually configured. (Because I usually code another languages in another IDE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any more configuration after install pthreads from nuget?

Using **Nuget** format to install `pthread` into C++ projects is quite simple and will not manually configure `include Directories` and `additional Dependencies` address any more.

But [pthread nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pthreads/) in VS has a drawback that it does not fully inherit `pthread` class library. It lost a file called `pthreadvc2.lib`.  You can try my following suggestions to configure it without any settings in `project properties`.

**Solution**

**1)** download `pthread-w32-2-9-1-release.zip` from [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/).

**2)** unpack this file and then copy `pthreadVC2.lib` from the file(`pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\Pre-built.2\lib\x86 or x64`) into

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\xxxxx\VC\Tools\MSVC\xxxx.xx.xxxx\lib\x86 or x64`.

**Note** that you should copy the related lib into the related folder, `x86 pthreadVC2.lib` into `x86` folder, `x64 pthreadVC2.lib` into `x64` folder.

**3)** then add this into your cpp file:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"pthreadVC2.lib")
```

Then it will work as expected without any errors.

Comment: You are awesome!! I couldn't find this solution in any document. How did you know that?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and just some tests confirm it :) Besdies, If you have any other issues about nuget later, please feel free to let us know.  Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: The zip file's link was dead. I replaced it with a working one. And the answer is solved my problem also. Thank you!